# How to add a timer in a C++ program

Tags: c++, timer

I'm making a game in C++ i.e. hangman in which for entering each letter as an input I want to give user a time limit of 20 seconds. In those 20 seconds if input letter is not given then program ends with display "Time is up".
Remember 'while the timer is running' I want to give input letter.

Is that possible?

Please help through code implementation.

Comment: How exactly should such a timer work?

Comment: Have you considered using threads?

Comment: need some more details: what platform? what framework library? But in general: it is possible to add a timer

Comment: What is your attempt?

Comment: `delay(millisecs)` is that you asking for?

Comment: Well, Using a normal Dev C++ orwel 5.6.2 compiler is what I'm using and Timer should work like when my game starts it gives a time of 2 minutes for the whole word to be guessed (game is Hangman) or it should give 40 seconds for the each word to be guessed. Game is console based program... 
No framework...
I'm unable to work it with threads.. The timer starts but m unable to give the input letter for my word(in the game).
Delay should be in seconds...

Comment: 40 seconds for the each letter to be guessed.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your platform has `conio.h` available and your compiler supports C++11 (including `<chrono>`) you can do it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <conio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start;
  start = std::chrono::system_clock::now(); /* start timer */
  while(true){
    __int64 secondsElapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now()-start).count();
    if(secondsElapsed >= 20){ /* 20 seconds elapsed -> leave main lopp */
      break;
    }
    if(_kbhit()){ /* keypressed */
      char c = _getch(); /* get character */
      std::cout << c; /* output character to stdout */
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

After 20 seconds are passed the programm terminates - until that, you can enter characters to the console window (tested on Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2012).

See also the documentation for [`_kbhit()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58w7c94c.aspx), [`_getch()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak.aspx) and [`<chrono>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/).

Comment: Could you please explain this code line wise since <chrono> library is new for me. As I have somehow implemented it my code...

Comment: @user3701934 I've commented almost each line already. What part exactly do you have problems with? The variable `secondsElapsed` will hold the current time minus the time, when the timer started. To use such a timer, it's important that you won't use `scanf` or `std::cin` (because blocking Input won't terminate the timer immediately) - that's why I've used `_kbhit()` and `_getch()` instead.

Comment: What about the arguments in int main() and what
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start; this 
and this  __int64 secondsElapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now()-start).count(); line does

Comment: Besides that this is hell awesome and I have made it work according to my program... This is the best help I got and best explanation I got... (y)
Thanks alot...

Comment: @user3701934 You can just leave the arguments from `int main()` out - these are not necessary for each modern compiler, but I typed them, because that's how main is defined typically (the parameters represent command line options). The line `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start;` declares a timer-variable - and the line after that starts the timer. `__int64 secondsElapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now(​)-start).count()` will just take the current time in seconds and subtracts the start timer from it!

Comment: @user3701934 Please make sure to mark this answer as accepted, if it solved your problem (to do so, just click on the checkmark on the left side of the post) - thank you.

Comment: Can you add a display as well of this timer ? While the timer runs it also displays them(seconds).

Comment: @user3701934 You just have to add an `std::cout << secondsElapsed << std::endl;` in the mainloop to output the value from the timer (or `std::cout << 20 - secondsElapsed << std::endl;` to display the remaining time instead). But of course that will have strange effects, with your console window (because if you display the time -> where should the Keyboard-input be displayed? the command line window will scroll down and the keyboard-input is just printed on the current line when it was detected). If you have further questions, please ask a new question on StackOverflow.